# How to add columns dynamically in the PIVOT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a #temp table in that the data is like [This is not the actual data but similar to this], I have filled that data by using Dynamic PIVOT

```
Name      Department  Div   Science Maths  Bio
Prashant    CSE        A    20      NULL   NULL
Prashant    CSE        A    NULL    50     NULL
Lisa       CBSE        A    11      NULL   NULL
Lisa       CBSE        A    NULL    90     NULL
Lisa       CBSE        A    NULL    NULL   56
```

So what I want is,

```
Name      Department    Div Science Maths   Bio
Prashant    CSE         A   20      50     NULL
Lisa       CBSE         A   12      90     56
```

The dynamic SQL what I have used [Actual Query which produce an output like first table:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    N'SELECT departmentName as Department,EmployeeCode as EmpCode,
    designationName as Designation,employeeName as EmployeeName,NatureofActivity,
       oversightCode,'+@selectCols+'
    INTO ##TempPivot
    FROM #OVERSIGHTANDCOETABLE
    PIVOT(SUM(percentage) 
          FOR name IN (' + @cols + ')) AS PVTTable PIVOT
          (
          MAX(OversightFunction) 
          FOR name1 IN (' + @displayCols + ')) AS PVTTable1'
```

Comment: Please show the original data and query.  The current output is fine, but we need to see this other data as well to give an exact answer (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Have added

Comment: The dynamic query you posted does not seem to match the current output.

Comment: yes as the actual data and query is long so have posted the sample data

Comment: I'm not sure how/why this needs to be dynamic. The data isn't being pivoted, it's being aggragated; thus the column names will be a known. If it's a case of you only want certain ones displayed, handle that in your presentation layer.

Comment: What you want can be achieved simply by a GROUP BY clause as suggested by Chanukya. You don't need a PIVOT query here

Comment: @Larnu the data I provided is only sample, I want to make rows to the column which the data is available in `@selectCols`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that isn't sample data then. Provide with data representative of what it looks like, not a version that is malformed from a part solution. That doesn't give us a good idea what your needs are. If we see the original data, finding a solution to help you will be far easier for us,

Answer (score 2):

Try this option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- your current dynamic query
)

SELECT
    Name,
    Department, 
    Div,
    MAX(Science) AS Science,
    MAX(Maths) AS Maths,
    MAX(Bio) AS Bio
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Name,
    Department, 
    Div;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` `functions` to get required output

```
 select Name,max(Department), max(Div), max(Science),max( Maths) ,max(  Bio)
    from table
    group by Name
```

Comment: The column names are dynamic

Comment: @PrashantPimpale please keep output in one temp table and do like this it will work

Comment: @PrashantPimpale since you can keep max function in dynamic query but group by should be happen based on name means you have to keep in (separate table or or with CTE)  these things should be used to get required answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have made changes with hardcoded columns name but i need that dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```